# Creating a reusable datastore client for large flask application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, google-cloud-datastore

I want to create a database connection from my python flask application to my datastore instance on GCP. I have a file services/db.py:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
from google.auth import compute_engine
from config import env
import os
import logging
import warnings

namespace = env.str('ENV')


class Datastore_Client():

    def context_local(self):
        datastore_client = datastore.Client(namespace=namespace)
        return datastore_client

    def context_test(self):
        project = env.str("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT")
        credentials = compute_engine.Credentials()
        datastore_client = datastore.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project, namespace='test')
        return datastore_client

    def context_live(self):
        datastore_client = datastore.Client(namespace=namespace)
        return datastore_client

    def get_datastore_client(self):
        contexts = {
            'local': self.context_local,
            'test': self.context_test,
            'appengine': self.context_live
        }

        context_func = contexts.get(env.str("CONTEXT"), self.context_local)

        return context_func()

    builtin_list = list

    def from_datastore(self, entity):
        if not entity:
            return None
        if isinstance(entity, list):
            entity = entity.pop()

        return entity
```

In my model files I would reference the datastore client like so:

```
from ..services.db import Datastore_Client
client = Datastore_Client().get_datastore_client()
```

but in providing this reference in all files which need it when running my application it seems to spin up a database connection for each instance whereas I would want an application wide connection.

I have looked at application context but with example using sqlite and talking about tearing down the connection after I am not sure if the same approach can be used for datastore.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an object everytime you call Datastore_Client().  It sounds like you want to create a [Singleton](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html) Datastore_Client and use that in your model files.

Comment: Thanks @jim. I'll look into this approach and let you know if I have any success.